# Grails: Foreign key as primary key?

Tags: sql, grails, grails-domain-class

first of all i have to say that i have an existing database that it can not be modify (that´s why i am having this problem)

I have two cases, the first one is this:
In this case the id (primary key) must be a foreign key as well. The code that i put, it doesn´t work.

```
class SbPEstadoComponente {

    static mapping = {
         table 'SB_P_ESTADO_COMPONENTE'         
         version false
         idEstadoComponenteHxPEstado column:'ID_ESTADO_COMPONENTE'
     id column:'ID_ESTADO_COMPONENTE'
    }

    // Relation
    SbPDemora idEstadoComponenteHxPEstado
    String facturable
    ..
    ..
    ..
}
```

In the other case the table has 3 columns, that coluns are foreign key to 3 tables.  Also those 3 columns have to be a composite primary key.

Any ideas? sugestions?
Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

In your child class's mapping you need `id composite: ['fkey1', 'fkey2']` and `implements Serializable`

Note that when you do a `get` you will need to populate all the composite key values